# Cannot install nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 22.04 GCP VM with secure boot

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I followed the straightforward guide [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/install-drivers-gpu#secure-boot) to no avail: after successfully running `sudo apt -y install linux-modules-nvidia-535-gcp nvidia-driver-535` and rebooting the VM, `nvidia-smi` returns

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

What's puzzling is that this process worked before for other VMs using secure boot and the same Ubuntu 22.04 image. I'm at a loss as to how to debug what went wrong.